# I am having issues with my Date field while loading it into elasticsearch. Its not coming as proper Date

Tags: java, date, elasticsearch, timestamp, kibana

Here is my getter setter code :

```
 public Date getUpdateTime() {
    return UpdateTime;
}

public void setUpdateTime(Date UpdateTime) {
    this.UpdateTime = UpdateTime;
}
```

Here is my mapping to the elasticsearch :

```
 event.get(i).setUpdateTime(rs.getDate("UpdateTime").toLocalDate().format(formatter));
```

Here is my formatter:

```
String pattern = "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSS";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
```

The value coming from the database is in below format , How to get the value in the same format in elasticSearch :

```
2020-05-18 08:45:13
```

Comment: Hey @GKr297, I don't quite understand your question- what do you mean how to get the same value in ES? also, i suggest you to work with ISO8601 time format, which is supported by ELK.

Comment: By same value, I meant the value in the same format

Comment: @GKr297 can you share your complete code, i want to try myself , its better if you can share github link with readme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the Date field as string, convert the setters/ getters data type as String, elasticsearch will get it in correct format :

```
event.get(i).setUpdateTime(rs.getString("UpdateTime"))
```

You can use Substring if you don't need milliseconds.